# How can I know how the exit() function work?

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a small program to find how the exit() function works in Linux.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()

{
    exit(0);
}
```

And then I compiled the program with gcc.

```
gcc -o  example -g -static example.c
```

In gdb, when I set a breakpoint, I got these lines.

```
Dump of assembler code for function exit:
0x080495a0 <+0>:    sub    $0x1c,%esp
0x080495a3 <+3>:    mov    0x20(%esp),%eax
0x080495a7 <+7>:    movl   $0x1,0x8(%esp)
0x080495af <+15>:   movl   $0x80d602c,0x4(%esp)
0x080495b7 <+23>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x080495ba <+26>:   call   0x80494b0 <__run_exit_handlers>
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) b 0x080495a3
Function "0x080495a3" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (0x080495a3) pending.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jack/Documents/overflow/example
[Inferior 1 (process 2299) exited normally]
```

The program does not stop at the breakpoint. Why? I use -static to compile the program, why does the breakpoint pend until the library loads into the memory?

Comment: Try adding the flag -O0 (big o zero) to your compilation. This  will set optimization to the lowest and therefore the assembler code would probably be more easy to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking gdb to break on a function called `0x080495a3`. You'll need to use `b *0x080495a3` instead.

```
(gdb) help break
Set breakpoint at specified line or function.
break [LOCATION] [thread THREADNUM] [if CONDITION]
LOCATION may be a line number, function name, or "*" and an address.
```

As the help says,  The `*` tells gdb it's an address you want to break on.

From your example:

```
Function "0x080495a3" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (0x080495a3) pending.
```

The "pending" means that the breakpoint is waiting until a function called `0x080495a3` is loaded from a shared library.

---

You might also be interested in `break-range`:

```
(gdb) help break-range
Set a breakpoint for an address range.
break-range START-LOCATION, END-LOCATION
where START-LOCATION and END-LOCATION can be one of the following:
 LINENUM, for that line in the current file,
 FILE:LINENUM, for that line in that file,
 +OFFSET, for that number of lines after the current line
         or the start of the range
 FUNCTION, for the first line in that function,
 FILE:FUNCTION, to distinguish among like-named static functions.
 *ADDRESS, for the instruction at that address.

The breakpoint will stop execution of the inferior whenever it executes
an instruction at any address within the [START-LOCATION, END-LOCATION]
range (including START-LOCATION and END-LOCATION).
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that you're trying to set a breakpoint at a function named `0x080495a3`. Instead try `b *0x080495a3` to indicate to GDB that you want to break at a specific address.

Answer (score 1):

0x080495a3 is an address of the line on which you are willing to apply break point. But the format for gdb is b (function name or line number). So You have 2 ways to do this.

1) do an l after your gdb session has started. It will list you the code in C. And then apply a break point using the line number else

2) if you want to use the address, use b *0x080495a3 way to set a break point.

This way you will be able to halt at line

0x080495a3 <+3>:    mov    0x20(%esp),%eax